# Gastby stops serving site locally on specific operations

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm, gatsby

I have a project in react and gatsby and when I run yarn start, it builds everything for me and starts serving the project on http://localhost:8000. But when I do specific operations, like go to a 404 page or open the Chrome Dev tools, it stops serving the project and return the following error:

[gatsby error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGvKJ.png)

```
 ERROR 

Cannot read property 'matchPath' of undefined



  TypeError: Cannot read property 'matchPath' of undefined
  
  - render-dev-html.ts:144 
    [web]/[gatsby]/src/utils/dev-ssr/render-dev-html.ts:144:17
  
  - new Promise
  
  - render-dev-html.ts:134 renderDevHTML
    [web]/[gatsby]/src/utils/dev-ssr/render-dev-html.ts:134:3
  
  - start-server.ts:502 
    [web]/[gatsby]/src/utils/start-server.ts:502:40
  


✨  Done in 290.00s.
```

I'm using MacOS 11.4 and node/npm version is 12.13.1/6.12.1

Answer (score 0):

I did have a similar issue and it does not happen if I add the following code to `gatsby-config.js`:

```
...
  flags: {
    DEV_SSR: false,
  },
...
```